# vue-google-charts error n.load is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, gchart

I'm using the vue-google-charts package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-google-charts) to display google charts in my application (vuejs2.x) and until now it worked perfectly fine.

But now i get the following error:

> ```
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: n.load is not a function
>     at vue-google-charts.common.js:1
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at vue-google-charts.common.js:1
> ```

and in my code the following messages shows up:
[image]

I read in several articles that i can create a file vendor.d.ts and put the following inside:

```
declare module 'vue-google-charts';
```

I created this file and placed it in the "src" folder but it still doesn't work. The problem is, that when I test it locally the application works perfect, all graphs are displayed etc. but as soon as I deploy the application to firebase the graphs don't work anymore.

I also read that the problem can be solved by put the following setting in the tsconfig.json file:

```
"noImplicitAny": false
```

But I don't have a tsconfig.json file I only have package.json and vue.config.js. so don't know where to put this setting.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any answer to this problem but I figured out that this problem only exists in the index.vue page. If I use another page the problem vanishes.

So i created a second page with the graph inside and redirected the index-site to the second page with the graphs.

I know it doesn't answer the problem but it is a workaround I can live with.